# Postman Returns HTML which shows can not Post even though my API route is correct

Tags: api, express, postman

when i make Post API request from postman it returns HTML showing can not POST, which means that there is some problem with my API but i think my API is correct.

```js
// @route    POST api/posts/comment/:id
// @desc     Comment on a post
// @access   Private
router.post(
  '/comment/:id',
  [
    auth,
    checkObjectId('id'),
    [check('text', 'Text is required').not().isEmpty()],
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
      const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

      const newComment = {
        text: req.body.text,
        name: user.name,
        avatar: user.avatar,
        user: req.user.id,
      };

      post.comments.unshift(newComment);

      await post.save();

      res.json(post.comments);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);
```

server.js snippet where i appended all APIs

```js
/Define routes

app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));
```

[Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekIOO.png)

Comment: where is your server .js did you injected your router to server

Comment: yes i injected all my routes to server

Comment: use `console.log( require('./routes/api/posts'))`  in your server.js you can figure out whether you exported properly or not

Answer (score 0):

looking at the screenshot you have attached, here are my observations.

1. The response you receive is actually a 404. This indicates that the path you are calling does not exist. Ensure that the API Endpoint is correct.
2. The `x-auth-token` has a Quote `"` in it which isn't correct.

Comment: 1- I attached the code snippet i think my API endpoint is correct,please have a look at that.
2- I noticed that quote and remove it still i am getting the same error

Comment: I dont see a 'posts' keyword in your endpoint. Are you appending it inside your main JS File? like app.js?

Comment: Yes, I appended that in my server.js file.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add that file / Screenshot of it as well?

Comment: Done, have a look

Comment: Have you added a `module.exports = your_router_variable` in your router file?

Comment: Yes i added that. All other APIs are working fine which is in the same file except the one i attached